# Updating Password in sql database using text-box

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, sql-server-ce

using ASP.NET & VB.NET i trying to update the user password, where it is equals to the sessionID

Database using is SQL Local.

here is the vb .net code

```
    Dim pass As String
    pass = tboxConFirmPass.Text

    Dim connce As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString())
    connce.Open() 'make the connection to DB
    Dim sqlCommand As String = "UPDATE [tbCustomer] SET [Password] = ('" _
                            + tboxConFirmPass.Text + "', '" + "WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID" + "')"

    Dim cmd As SqlCeCommand = New SqlCeCommand(sqlCommand, connce)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    connce.Close()
    MsgBox("Your Password has been chaged.")

End Sub
```

here is the `SqlDataSource`

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbCustomer] SET [Password] = @Password WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID">
```

Error = There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 42,Token in error = , ]

Comment: You didn't mentioned what error or problem you are facing with the codes.  Simply passing the codes won't helpout.

Comment: What problem are you seeing?

Regardless, this is vulnerable to SQL injection. And your sqlCommand text looks wrong (quotes in the wrong places).

Comment: the error is; There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 42,Token in error = , ]

Comment: I have try the Solution and get this error; A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 1

Answer (score 0):

Right, your query needs to be changed thus:

```
Dim sqlCommand As String = "UPDATE [tbCustomer] SET [Password] = '" _
                            & Replace(tboxConFirmPass.Text, "'", "''") & "' WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID"
```

I've sorted your brackets and quotes mismatches out, changed the string concatenation operator to & and put an escape in to reduce the possibility of SQL injection vulnerability (if someone puts a single quote in their password, your query will no longer fall over, or worse).

To set a value for @CustomerID you need to add a SQL Parameter to the command object. If you don't give it a value you'll get the error mentioned in your comment. Alternatively you can concatenate the value like you do with the password:

```
Dim sqlCommand As String = "UPDATE [tbCustomer] SET [Password] = '" _
                                & Replace(tboxConFirmPass.Text, "'", "''") & "' WHERE [CustomerID] = " & CustomerID
```

Note that you will need to use a variable that is initialised with the ID of the customer whose password is being changed.

Comment: I have try the Solution above and get this error; A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 1 ]